# Erro ao pegar dados do input radio

Tags: php, html, mysql, undefined

Galera, estou tendo o seguinte problema ao enviar o formulário:
[image: Mensagem de erro ao enviar o formulário]

Segue parte do código do formulário e da validação:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sexoFunc" class="control-label col-sm-2">Sexo:</label>
      <div class="radio-inline">
        <label for="masc">
          <input type="radio" value="M" name="optradio" id="masc">Masculino</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio-inline">
        <label for="fem">
          <input type="radio" value="F" name="optradio" id="fem">Feminino</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Validação onde esta ocorrendo o erro na linha 22]

*É a minha primeira vez postando no Stack, desculpa se fiz algo errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro indica que não há um valor na sua variável `$_POST` com o nome "sexoFunc".

O formulário indica que o `name` do `radio button` é **optradio** e não **sexoFunc**. O `$_POST` pega o valor pelo `name` do elemento enviado pelo formulário.

Altere o `$_POST` para `$_POST["optradio"]` ou os `name`s dos `radio`s para `sexoFunc`.